# Lifting automorphism problem - classical approach

Tags: graph-theory

Let X, Y be  connected  graph and Y be a covering  graph of X and  A be asubgroup of Aut(X). let B be lift of A. we know  there is a group epimorphism from B to A. What is this epimorphism?

Comment: I am puzzled, the dodecahedral graph is a double cover of the Petersen graph. The automorphism group of the Petersen graph has order 120 and the automorphism of the dodecahedral graph has order 60. So if we take $A$ to be the automorphism group of the Petersen graph, it cannot lift.

Comment: Automorphism of the dodecahedral graph has order 120, see it http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PlatonicGraph.html

Comment: You're right, I do not know where I got that 60 from. But the Klein graph on 24 vertices has automorphism group of order 336 and is a 3-fold cover of $K_8$. I expect that few covers of complete graph $K_n$ admit the symmetric group $S_n$ as a group of automorphisms,

Comment: But I saw in some article that there is a group epimorphism from lift of A to A. for example in lifting graph automorphism by voltage assignments(http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669800903901 ), section 5.

Comment: If you choose your voltage assignment correctly, you _may_ be able to lift a subgroup. But the example I gave shows you cannot always do it.

Comment: Let X be a connected graph and N be a normal subgroup of Aut(X) and X be regular covering of quoetient graph X coresponging to orbite N ,X\N. let A be a subgroup of Aut(X\N). Can I say there is a group epimorphism from lift of A to A? if yes, What is this epimorphism?

Comment: If I take $N=1$ in your comment, your question is just your original question restricted to regular covers. But if you look at 2-fold covers of $K_n$, I am sure you will find examples where $S_n$ does not act on the cover.